# Do multiple normalizing modules conflict with each other?

Tags: 8

Drupal Core serialization service is selecting normalizers from container by looking at "normalizer" tags and their priorities. But we have multiple modules using serialization, providing their own normalizers for the same entity types/fields, for example: *jsonapi* and *hal*. Knowing how Drupal is selecting normalizers, it looks like it has to always select the higher priority one, and multiple modules using serialization, and providing their own normalizers to the same entities, are inherently conflicting with each other.

Am I missing something?